# Firebase data not plotting in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, highcharts

I would like to use Highcharts to plot a graph using my Firebase data. The axes of the graph showed up but I failed to plot the graph.

[This is the data printed on my HTML console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuCm1.png)

Javascript code that I'm using:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var dbRef0 = firebase.database().ref().child("");
var dbRef1 = firebase.database().ref().child("Meter2");
var dataSetFirebaseTotalActivePower1 = [];

dbRef1.limitToLast(20).on('child_added',function(snap) {
    var TotalActivePower1 = snap.val().totalActivePower;
    var Time1 = snap.val().time;
    dataSetFirebaseTotalActivePower1.push({x: Time1 ,y: TotalActivePower1});
    console.log(dataSetFirebaseTotalActivePower1);
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Total Active Power Graph'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && 
            Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: 'Time'
        },
        plotBands: [{ 
            from: 4.5,
            to: 6.5,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
        }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total Active Power, kWh'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' units'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [dataSetFirebaseTotalActivePower1]
    }]
});
```

The chart appears, but empty.

Comment: Could you possibly explain _how_ this doesn't work? What is the problem with this code?

Comment: It doesn't seem to push the firebase data to into the series at all....I am wondering if my data formatting goes wrong?

Comment: @Adam What does `console.log(dataSetFirebaseTotalActivePower1);` print?

Comment: @Codeer, I have updated my post. Please check the printed data on the link.

Comment: Change `data: [dataSetFirebaseTotalActivePower1]` to `data: dataSetFirebaseTotalActivePower1` as it is already an array of objects.

Comment: Hi @wergeld I have solved the problem. I use Jaime's method. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart configuration looks good to me, what you're experiencing is that the data from firebase comes in asynchronously, which means that at the time the chart is created, your array is empty, and only then the nodes start pouring in, one by one.

Instead of populating the results array you could add the data directly to the charts, via [addPoint](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint) API call:

> Add a point to the series after render time. The point can be added at the end, or by giving it an X value, to the start or in the middle of the series.

Try this update to your `child_added` event callback:

```
dbRef1.limitToLast(20).on('child_added', function(snap) {
    var TotalActivePower1 = snap.val().totalActivePower;
    var Time1 = snap.val().time;
    var DataPoint = { x: Time1, y: TotalActivePower1 };
    chart.series[0].addPoint(DataPoint, true);
});
```

It may be useful for you to understand [Why are the Firebase API asynchronous?](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)

Comment: Awesome! Now if you could please accept the answer so people know this is solved :)